# Which epic happens in Kali yuga, like Ramayana happened in Treta yuga and Mahabharata happened in Dwapara yuga?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, yuga, kali-yuga

The epics Ramayana and Mahabharata happened in Treta yuga and Dwapara yuga respectively. Likewise, is there any epic which will take place in Kali yuga?

Comment: Both the epics depict the two avatars of Lord Vishnu defeating Adharma and restoring Dharma on earth.So,when Kalki avatar appears there is a possibility of another epic.

Comment: @Yogi Ramayana happened in 24th Treta Yuga and Mahabhartha in 28th Dwapara Yuga.

Comment: This is broad question. As others said, Story of Kalki may be epic for this Kali Yuga. But still no one is sure about it.

Comment: @AnilKumar Still 24th is prior to 28 I didn't remember exact numbers so I said previous mahayugas, anyway thankyou for information.

Comment: Ramayana happened in previous treta yuga while mahabharata war was fought in this dwapara yuga. The difference if of mahayuga cycles. Each mahayuga has its own vyasa, and your vyasa krishna dwaipayana was generous enough to give us epics like Mahabharata. While ramayana is preserved from previous mahayugas, note that there is no pralaya kala between two mahayugas. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_units_of_time#For_Brahma. Talking about future epics only trikaldarshi sages would know what will happen.

Answer (score 4):

The episode of Kalki avatar of this 28th Chaturyuga cycle is not written anywhere, as it is not yet recorded in the Causal Ocean/Ocean of Events. It is Vishnu's Will and His Will only. Gods can know humans' wish and will, and can write down an entire story for what humans can do in the year 2110 AD. But knowing Vishnu's wish and will in the future is beyond their reach. So Kalki, who's not appeared yet is not recorded anywhere except the facts which were predetermined, like He will be born in Shambhala, will receive celestial weapons from Parashurama, will be assisted by Hanuman, etc.

Comment: Welcome TO Hinduism SE! Question / Answer forum about Hinduism.Although your answers are nice but are without any sources.On this site a answer should be backed by citing sources from authentic Hindu scriptures like Puranas , Gita etc.OR quotes of Acharyas ,pls. edit your answers and try to add sources in them.Visit Help Center - http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is a very broad question. I can only say epics do not happen because they have to happen. Great sages from ancient times written those great works to mention coming generations about how they need to lead life and what happened to various people who obeyed or disobeyed god and dharma. These epics are serving the sole purpose of enlighting the generations. Kaliyuga is the last part of the Mahayuga (which contains kruthayuga, threthayuga, dwaparayuga, kaliyuga) and after kaliyuga the clock resets to kruthayuga where these dharmas are no longer valid and have more stricter rules.

Anlayzing those epics what scholars conclude is in kruthayuga the god and bad are separated by planets. Gods recided in urdhva lokas and demons in adho lokas, and whenever there are problems, god took incarnation of some form and killed those demons. In threthayuga, good and bad were in the same world and separated by kingdoms (Rama and Ravana). God just not changed his form, but rather took birth, and he not only killed ravana but also showed the world how one should lead life to attain higher world and ultimately moksha. In dwaparayuga, good and bad were in the same family (Kauravas and Pandavas), then god motivated good people, corrected them, and made them kill the bad ones. He did not do it by himself.

In kaliyuga good and bad are in the same person, no one is perfectly good or bad. So in kaliyuga people do not change much by teachings or preachings or even model living, and people tend to become more bad as the kaliyuga progresses. Hence the only way to correct is by creating maha pralaya (destruction as kalki).

Comment: This does not answer the question. I don't think the question is broad

Comment: @user5155835 The answer is in the second line itself: _epics do not happen because they have to happen_

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking of Lords Appearance in this world in Kali Yuga? Then the answer is Yes. [Sri Chaitnya MahaPrabhu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitanya_Mahaprabhu) appeared in Bengal around 500 years ago. The entire episode is elaborately described in the epics, if you like to call it that way, [Chaitanya Charitamrita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitanya_Charitamrita), [Chaitanya Bhagavata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitanya_Bhagavata) and [Chaitanya Mangala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitanya_Mangala)

He appearied especially to deliver the people of this age.

Comment: Lord's avatar in Kali Yuga is the Kalki avatar and not Chaitanya Maha Prabhu.

Comment: Wait. No wonder, Sri Chaitnya Mahaprabhu is called Chenna Avatar, an incarnation not as clear as others.

Comment: An avatar's role is quite clear in scriptures:To erase adharma by eliminating the demonic forces and thereby restoring Dharma on earth.And it is quite clear that Chaitanya Maha Prabhu has done nothing of that sort.Even Sri adi Shankaracharya is considered an incarnation of Lord Shiva but we are not talking about that.BTW,it was not me who have downvoted your answer.:)

Comment: Again wait. You say its clear that Chaitanya Maha Prabhu has not done anything to establish Dharma?? On what basis. He inaugurated sankirtana movement, the Congricational Chanting of Lords names himself, which is the dharma of the current age. "harer-nama harer-nama harer-namaiva kevalam kalau nasty-eva nasty-eva nasty-eva gatir anyatha"
‘Harinama, Harinama, Harinama is the only and foremost means to achieve emancipation. There is no other way, no other way, no other way in this age of Kali. And he started this movement and its now spreading all over the world. Now you say, he is not Avatar.

Comment: Erasing adhrama????In today's world adharma is increasing at an exponential rate and it will be like that only till it reaches a maximum point after which there is no increase possible.And ,at that time Lord Vishnu's Kalki avatar will appear to restore dharma on earth.:)

Comment: ." Now you say, he is not Avatar"-He is certainly not one among the 10 avatars of the Lord that we know of .:)

Comment: @VivekDev Only Gaudiya Vasihnavaites give importance to Chaitanya Mahaprabhu, not all. However, this answer is irrelevant here as it talks about Avatars which are more or less complete like Krishna and Rama.

Comment: @Rickross Regarding Dasavatar there is no strong evidence to prove it. Vishnu Avatars are unlimited.  See [comments under this question](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7189/3500) which gives chronological order of Vishnu Avatars and major events.

Comment: @Anil, I am talking about incarnations of Vishnu only and not anything else. Take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitanya_Mahaprabhu#Identity). There you find: **The Gaudiya Vaishnava acharya Bhaktivinoda Thakura have also found out the rare manuscript of Caitanya Upanishad of the atharvaveda section, which reveals the identity of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu**

Comment: @Rickross, As far as I know the 10 Avatars as people know, is made famous by the [Jaya Deva Goswamis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jayadeva) [dasavatara Stotra mala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Works_of_Jayadeva#Dashavatara). But no where its written that they are the only 10. For example Bhagavata purana describes more.

Comment: Can you share that Caitanya Upanishad of Atharva Veda @VivekDev! I am eager to read that.

Comment: @VivekDev you said that "Harinama, Harinama, Harinama is the only and foremost means to achieve emancipation. " I.e. Vakti is the ONLY path in kali yuga. Which is not true though...

Comment: @Rickross, Bhagavan's avatars are not limited to 10. Avatars are also not limited to direct descending. He can send a jiva-atma in his place too. e.g. Parashuram is one of 10 avatars, but it's not Bhagavan himself. It's avesha avatar. Depending on the sankalp of avatar, he can decide how many bad guys to 'erase', and how many to leave. It does not necessarily mean all bad guys will be removed. If that was the case, then no need for dharma to decline after he leaves.

Comment: @ram that is not true do your homework.

Comment: @Vivekdev Chaitanya was just a normal person nothing more.

Comment: @Wikash_, Duryodhana did not accept Krishna was Bhagavan even after seeing him in person. Nothing new to see here folks..

Comment: @ram I was not talking about that part.

Answer (score 1):

Kalki is the Avatar of Kaliyuga. Though Lord Venkateswara is born to fulfill some of the promises he made in previous incarnations but he didnt kill any evil.

Logically Kalki will fight with Kali who is the head of Lust, gold etc..
currently kali is not visible to the physical world. so Kalki will be too.

Kalki will fight with Kali in a different dimension i guess.

Why im saying like this is, in previous incarnations does asuras physically exist in the world and people were able to see the vishu avatar physically.
Now Kali born before end of Dwapar and he does still exist but we cannot see him.

Comment: If you cannot see Kali then how do you know he exists?

Comment: @Wikash_ as I said its a logical guess and not written anywhere. there are several mentions in vedic texts that Kali born in the end period of Dwapar Yuga.  If he was born already we should be seeing him. The birth of Kalki  is to demolish the evils within self.

Comment: So the Kali yuga has not started yet?