# why no epic is there in Kaliyuga like Ramayan and Mahabharat?

Tags: yuga

Like Ramayan and Mahabharat, Is there any epic happened or yet to happen in Kaliyuga? This [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10587/which-epic-happens-in-kali-yuga-like-ramayana-happened-in-treta-yuga-and-mahabh) is related but no proper resources.

It is said that all the four Yugas have repeated multiple times. And every Yugas events were written in puranas but except of Kali Yug, why?

From this question [do Vedas talk about Avatars?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22618/do-vedas-talk-about-avataras)
The answer says yes then what about Kalki Avatar written in Veda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Like Ramayan and Mahabharat, Is there any epic happened or yet to happen in Kaliyuga?**

Duplicate of [Which epic happens in Kali yuga, like Ramayana happened in Treta yuga and Mahabharata happened in Dwapara yuga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10587/which-epic-happens-in-kali-yuga-like-ramayana-happened-in-treta-yuga-and-mahabh)

**It is said that all the four Yugas have repeated multiple times. And every Yugas events were written in puranas but except of Kali Yug, why?**

Wrong question, events of Kali Yuga are written in Pratisarga Parva of Bhavishya Purana and in 6th part of Vishnu Purana.

[image]

If you can read Hindi then, you may read [this](https://vedpuran.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/bavishya-puran.pdf) (Introduction page 6 - 16 and Pratisarga Parva from page 234 - 275). Or in summary, you can read from [this](http://www.gita-society.com/scriptures/ALL18MAJORPURANAS.IGS.pdf) (page 843 to 855) or [this](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/bhavishya_purana/index.html).

**From this question do Vedas talk about Avatars? The answer says yes then what about Kalki Avatar written in Veda?**

Vedas talk about only few Avataras and not all. Puranas tell about all avataras.

Comment: Can you share some stories from bhavishya Purana about Kali yuga?

Comment: @Parikshitha This is not in the scope of this question. However I have updated my answer with some sources, you may read from them.

Comment: Okay. I actually mean sharing privately through mail.

Comment: I learn more from this answer. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.