# Why the events mentioned in Ramayana and Mahabaratha only occured in sub continent?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, ramayana, puranas, science

Why the events mentioned in  Ramayana and Mahabharata only occurred in sub-continent? 
If there were any other civilization present during those period, Why they are not mentioned in the holy scriptures?

Comment: It's because Rama and Krishna born here. Mahabharat war occured approximately 5116 years ago in present yuga cycle. But Ramayana occured in 24rd tretha yuga. Which is some million years ago. See [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7175/did-the-mahabharata-and-the-ramayana-happen-in-the-current-yuga-cycle-in-the-cur)