# Why did ravana live for so long?

Tags: ramayana, rama, karma, ravana

How could someone like ravana with not so many good karmas live for so long?

Answer (score 1):

At old times ages of people were so long.
And people dies when someone kills him or in a old age. This thing was also with Ravana. Any one was not able to kill him because he was very powerful and he also has vardan of Brahma and Shiva.
So this is the reason that he lived from 10th chaturyug of vaivaswat manvantara to 24th tretayug.

Comment: Please provide sources for your answer and especially the part mentioning that he lived from 10th Chaturyuga. Where did you read this?

Comment: This excerpt from the Prabhasa Kanda of the Skanda Purana describes age of Ravana.   ---.  Then for eighteen Yugas, the entire region of the three worlds was protected carefully by Mahendra....Kaikasi ... gave birth to Ravana who later became the lord of Rakshasas.... He was a king for fourteen ChaturYugas as a Rakshasa. O my beloved, in terms of years, the time extended to five crore sixty-one lakh sixty thousand years. ---. Since Ravana was killed in 24th tretayug it means he was living from 10th mahayuga

Comment: It says that Ravana 'ruled' those years. BTW, This passage is debatable because skanda purana belongs to a different kalpa. So it is possible that it's telling about a Ravana of different kalpa. We cannot be sure about Ravana's age. Here, refer these https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18211/26679 and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/51217/26679

Comment: I meant ravana a person with not so many good karma get to live so long and lavishly?@MysteryPedia