# Is the Valmiki Ramayana which is available to us , belongs to this Kalpa(Swetavaraha Kalpa)?

Tags: scripture, ramayana, rama, valmiki, kalpa

We know from various scriptures that Ramayana happened in the 24th Chaturyuga of the Vaivasvat Manvantara.

But does the Valmiki Ramayana which we all have and read in our homes , belong to this current Kalpa ?

**How correct would it be to say that the Valmiki Ramayanam present now belongs to this kalpa ?
What are the possible points we have to take into consideration ?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did the Mahabharata and the Ramayana happen in the current Yuga cycle in the current Manvantara?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7175/did-the-mahabharata-and-the-ramayana-happen-in-the-current-yuga-cycle-in-the-cur)

Comment: @hanugm No actually I'm not asking about the occurrence of Ramayana but about the version of Valmiki Ramayana which we have . Does it state to which Kalpa and all it belongs ? Also , I wanted to ask one more thing , is it possible that more than one kalpa have a manvantara named vaivasvata ?