# If the Ramyana we know happened in 24th Treta Yuga, what happened in 28th Treta Yuga?

Tags: history, rama, yuga, ramayana

According to [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7189) answer, Ramayana happened in 24th Treta Yuga.

If it happened in 24th Treta Yuga how did we come to know of it? Through which sage did we get the current available Valmiki Ramayana?

What happened in the current 28th Treta Yuga? Didn't a descendant of Rama fight in Mahabharata? Are the Puranas which are saying it happened in 24th Treta Yuga, talking about the available Ramayana or a previous Ramayana which is not available right now?

---

Summarizing the question

1. Did Valmiki who wrote the available Ramayana lived in 24th or 28th Tretayuga??
2. Did No Ramayana happen in 25th to 28th Treta Yuga? Especially what happened in the current Treta  Yuga?
3. How did descendant of Rama from 24th Treta Yuga fought in 28th Dwapara Yuga Mahabharata battle??

Comment: In current 28th Treta Yuga, Devi manifested as Ajapaleshvari for cure the diseases of a king named Ajapala. It is stated in Skanda Purana.

Answer (score 5):

Let it be known that the Ramayana occured 4 Yuga cycles before this, whilst Mahabharata occured in the 28th Dwapara Yuga.

> In the twenty-eighth aeon of Dwapara, there will be Dwaipayana Vyasa, the son of Parashara, and the most excellent of Purushas [Vishnu] shall be born as Krishna with his one-sixth part, as the foremost of the sons of Vasudeva. (Shatrudra Samhita, Shiva Purana.)

---

**How Ramayana became known to Valmiki**

1.) In the first Sarga of the Bala Kanda (First Book of Youth) in Ramayana, it describes:

Narada Muni, the master of sages, and the divine seer from Heaven, gives Valmiki a brief talk about who Rama was.

> tapaH svaadhyaaya nirataam tapasvii vaagvidaam varam |
> naaradam paripapracCha vaalmiikiH muni pu.mgavam || 1-1-1
>
> A thoughtful-meditator, an eternally studious sage in scriptures about the Truth and Untruth, a sagacious thinker, and a sublime enunciator among all expert enunciators is Narada, and with such a Divine Sage Narada, the Sage-Poet Valmiki is inquisitively enquiring about a man who is a composite for all merited endowments in his form and calibre. [1-1-1]
>
> The Sage-Poet Valmiki is inquisitively enquiring about a man who is a composite for all merited endowments in his form and calibre: "Who really is that person in this present world, who is principled and also a potential one, a conscientious one, a redeemer, and also a truth-teller and self-determined in his deed? Who is he conduct-wise blent with good-conduct. Who in respect of all beings is benign? Who is adept and also the ablest one [and] also uniquely good to look to? Who is that courageous one, who controlled his ire, who is brilliant, non-jealous and even whom do the gods fear, when provoked to war?"

Thus, Narada started briefly retelling who Rama was:

> ikSvaaku va.msha prabhavo raamo naama janaiH shrutaH |
> niyata aatmaa mahaaviiryo dyutimaan dhR^itimaan vashii || 1-1-8
>
> "One emerged from Ikshvaku dynasty and known to people as Rama by his name, and he is conscientious, highly valorous, resplendent, steadfast and a controller of vice and vile... and his own senses, as well... [1-1-8]
>
> raamasya dayitaa bhaaryaa nityam praaNa samaa hitaa || 1-1-26
> janakasya kule jaataa deva maayeva nir.hmitaa |
> sarva lakSaNa sa.mpannaa naariiNaam uttamaa vadhuuH || 1-1-27
> siitaapya anugataa raamam shashinam rohiNii yathaa |
>
> "Seetha, the best one among ladies, a possessor of all best qualities befitting to an ideal lady, the one who is as though fashioned by a Divine marvel, born in Janaka's family and became Dasharatha's daughter-in-law, and she who is the loving wife and an ever-amiable alter ego of Rama, even she followed Rama to forests, as with Lady Rohini following the Moon... [1-1-26b, 27, 28a]

This entire narration of Rama can be found [here.](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/bala/sarga1/bala_1_frame.htm)

Afterwards, Valmiki goes to a river to bathe himself and finds a hunter killing a bird. This enrages Valmiki, who curses the man. The curse is actually a verse from the Ramayana that he had never heard before, and this wasn't what Valmiki intended to say. It's rich in grammar. The full description can be found in the small introductory before the Sarga.

> Sage Valmiki goes to River Tamasa for a bath and sees a couple of birds, of which a hunter kills one. Valmiki unintentionally utters a poem, which is rich in grammar and new in metre, of which he is very much confused as to why such a poem has come from his tongue. Brahma, the presiding deity of letters appears and ordains Valmiki to author Ramayana, excellent epic of Rama, for which purpose alone he gave such divine meter and grammar to him.

Here is the sentence he uttered:

> tathaa vidhim dvijam dR^ishhTvaa nishhaadena nipaatitam |
> R^isheH dharmaatmaanaH tasya kaaruNyam samapadyata || 1-2-13
>
> On seeing at that bird felled that way by the tribal hunter, compassion is aroused in that kind-hearted sage Valmiki. [1-2-13]
>
> tataH karuNa veditvaat adharmo ayam iti dvijaH |
> nishaamya rudatiim krounchiim idam vacanam abraiit || 1-2-14
>
> Then on seeing the wailing female krounchi bird, compassion haunting him and apperceiving the killing of male bird as unjust, the sage uttered this sentence... [1-2-14]
>
> **maa nishhaada pratiSThaamtva | magamaH shaashvatiiH samaaH |
> yat krau~Ncha mithunaat eka | mavadhiiH kaama mohitam || 1-2-15**
>
> **"Oh! Ill-fated Hunter, by which reason you have killed one male bird of the couple, when it is in its lustful passion, thereby you will get an ever-lasting reputation for ages to come..." [1-2-15]**

Valmiki then ponderd about the sentence he just said:

> tasya evam bruvataH chintaa babhuuva hR^idi viikshataH |
> shokaartena asya shakuneH kim idam vyaahR^itam mayaa || 1-2-16
>
> On saying thus, and pondering for a while in his heart, 'annoyed by the anguish for that bird, what is it uttered by me...' thus he became cogitative of those lines uttered. [1-2-16]

Brahma goes to visit Valmiki and gives him the boon of remembering Rama's full story. He directs Valmiki to write it down.

> aajagaama tataH brahmo lokakartaa svayam prabhuH |
> chatur mukho mahaatejaa draSTum tam munipuN^gavam || 1-2-23
>
> Then, the great resplendent Four-faced creator of fourteen worlds, almighty Brahma, arrived there on his own, to see that eminent saint Valmiki. [1-2-23]
>
> tam uvaacha tato brahmaa prahasan munipu.ngavam | 1-2-30
> shloka evaastvayaam baddho na atra kaaryaa vichaaraNaa ||
>
> Then, Brahma smilingly spoke to that eminent saint Valmiki, "But, what that is composed is a verse only... and there is no need to think through... [1-2-30b-31a]
>
> mat cChandaat eva te brahman pravR^itte ayam sarasvatii | 1-2-31
> raamasya charitam kR^itsnam kuru tvam R^ishhisattama |
>
> "Oh, Brahman, that speech of yours sprang forth at my wish alone, hence oh, eminent sage, you shall render the legend of Rama, in its entirety... [1-2-31b-32a]
>
> dharmaatmano bhagavato loke raamasya dhiimataH || 1-2-32
> vR^ittam kathaya dhiirasya yathaa te naaradaat shrutam |
>
> "You shall narrate the legend of Rama, the virtuous, intellectual and an intrepid one, and a godlike person in this world as well, as you have heard it from sage Narada. [1-2-32b-33a]
>
> rahasyam cha prakaasham cha yad vR^ittam tasya dhiimataH || 1-2-33
> raamasya saha saumitre raakshasaanaam cha sarvashaH |
> vaidehyaaH cha eva yad vR^ittam prakaasham yadi vaa rahaH || 1-2-34
> tat ca api aviditam sarvam viditam te bhaviSyati |
>
> "The adventures of valorous Rama along with Lakshmana, and the misadventures of demons, known or unknown in every detail, and even the plight of Vaidehi which is either revealed or un-revealed so far, and whatever legend that has happened, all that will also be known to you, even if it were to be unknown, as yet... [1-2-33b-35a]

---

**Devi manisfated as Ajapaleshvari at current 28th Treta Yuga**

The below reference from [this chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc626846.html) Prabhasa-kshetra mahatmya of Skanda Purana mentiones what happened in the current Treta Yuga.

> 5. The earlier name of that goddess was Bhairavī.
>    There was a king named Ajāpāla in the beginning of the **Tretā Yuga of the twenty-eighth set of four Yugas** (Caturyuga) in this Manvantara.
> 6. O beautiful woman, he was afflicted by diseases. So he came to this holy spot. Goddess Bhairavī was adored by him in this Kṣetra for five hundred years.
> 7. The goddess who was pleased said to that excellent king: “Do not strain yourself, O saintly king, I am pleased with your devotion.”
> 8. On being told thus, the wise king joined his palms together. With his eyes dimmed with tears of joy, he bowed down and said to the goddess:
> 9. “O goddess, if you are pleased with me and if I deserve boons, may all the ailments in my body be destroyed and expelled.”
> 10. On being told thus the goddess said to the king again: “O great king, all will happen as mentioned now.”
> 11. As soon as it was uttered by the goddess, all the ailments came out severally from the body of the king in the form of goats.
> 12. These were definitely five thousand fifty of them. When this happened, the king was again addressed by the goddess:
> 13. “O king, take full care of these ailments in the forms of goats. They will be your servants carrying out your behests.
> 14. Your name will become well-known in the world as Ajāpāla and after your name, my name Ajāpāleśvarī shall spread over the earth till the Caturyuga is complete.

---

**The descendent of Rama fighting in Mahabharata**

Yes, it is true that a descendent of Rama did fight in Mahabharata, and did die. However, make no mistake, this man was not divine. He was simply a descendent of Rama's dynasty; the Ikshvaku, and since Rama was born to a normal kingdom called Ayodhya, he wasn't born special or anything.

His name was Brihadbala, and he was an unrighteous king who fought for the Kauravas. He was the son of Takshaka, grandson of Prasenajita, and great-grandson of Vishvahsa. He was the 117th generation of the Ikshvaku, and the very last of his lineage; and was killed by Abhimanyu during the Kurukshetra War. His brief story can be found in the Bhagvata Purana, book 9, Chapter 12.

> 8. Viśvasāhva’s son was Prasenajit whose son was Takṣaka; his son was Bṛhadbala who was killed in the battle by your father (Abhimanyu).

Another such reference can be found in the Brahmanda Purana, Book 3, Chapter 74. His details of his death isn't mentioned.

> 104-106. These are said to be the descendants of Ikṣvāku. They will be born in the Kaliyuga in the family of Bṛhadbala.
>
> They shall be endowed with great vigour and exploit. They will be heroic, learned and truthful. They will conquer the sense-organs.

Yet another reference can be found Vishnu Purana, Book 4, Chapter IV:

> his son was Viśrutavat[30]; and his son was Vrihadbala, **who was killed in the great war by Abhimanyu, the son of Añjuna.** These are the most distinguished princes in the family of Ikṣvāku: whoever listens to the account of them will be purified from all his sins[31].

---

I hope this cleared up any confusion or satiated any of your queries.

Comment: This answer said so many things without answering questions I asked. Let me rephrase mu question 1. Did Valmiki who wrote the available Ramayana lived in 24th or 28th Tretayuga??  2. Did No Ramayana happen in 28th Treta Yuga. 3. The Descendant of Rama from 24th Treta Yuga fought in 28th Dwapara Yuga??

Comment: @Chase My apologies, you didn't make your original questions clear enough.

Comment: 1. Valmiki lived in the 24th Dwapara Yuga. This can be asserted because in the list of "Veda Vyasas" in the Vishnu Purana, Valmiki was the 24th Veda Vyasa. One can only become a Veda Vyasa during Dwapara Yuga. Know though, that Valmiki *composed* the Ramayana, but he did not write the Ramayana. His composition was passed down verbally disciple to disciple until it made its way to the 28th Dwapara Yuga, when writing was long invented and could be written.

Comment: 2. No Ramayana happened in the 28th Treta Yuga. However, there is one problem. Though there are references in Puranas that this occured in 24th Treta Yuga, it doesn't make any sense. Due to the references of land, eclipses, and logical science (humans existed as far back as 2-4 million years, and each Mahayuga is 4.3 million years, meaning 4 Yuga cycles is about 16 million years, which is impossible unless it did not happen on Earth but rather a higher Lokah), we see that Ramayana happened 7,000 years ago whilst Mahabharata occured roughly 5,000 years ago.

Comment: 3. The descendent of Rama; Brihadbala, did not live in 24th Treta Yuga, that's absurd. There are over 40 million descendents still living, of the great Mongolian warrior and leader Genghis Khan. If I was one of them, it would be absurd to say I lived in the 1200s when Genghis Khan lived. No, instead he would be my great-great-great-great-great-great-great grandfather who lived 800 years ago.

Comment: @Harihara don't compare Modern Science with Vedic Knowledge. If scriptures say that it happened in 24th , it must have happened. We also have cross references for this in Skanda, Vayu and other puranas. We also have cosmic time duration regarding yugas kalpas etc. Modern science is always changing it's theories and coming nearer to the vedic things which shows that Vedic Knowledge is real.

Comment: @LSSJ Broly I do not regard the Puranas except the Vishnu Purana, Bhagvata Purana, and maybe the Shiva Purana occassionally, to be true. All other Puranas have been interpolated heavily over centuries. If it says somewhere that it happened in the 24th Treta Yuga in the Ramayana Ithihasa itself, then so be it, it must be true. If it doesn't, and we have it in Srimad Bhagvatam Purana, Vishnu or Shiva Purana, then yes, it also happened. And if it is in the Vedas, then it 100% happened. But, if I have to find cross-references to find in lower Puranas, it probably isn't true.

Comment: One example of interpolation of what I' saying is that the Skanda Purana, namely, says that Brahma is a post and any jiva can attain it within 100 rebirths (even gives 8 random names of "previous" Brahmas.) One other story was the story of Markandeya. It is well known that Shiva pardoned Markandeya and killed Yama temporarily. However, in the Skanda Purana, it says that Brahma granted him this boon, and that the Saptarishis brought Markandeya to Brahma.

Comment: Scriptures have many 'apparent' contradictions. If I'm able to recall correctly, the bhagvata has a different story altogether where Rishis Nara and Narayana have encounter with Markandeyaji and the incidents are different. If you disregard other puranas and say them 'lower puranas' and believe in only some 2-3 puranas then what can I say. If you believe in Shiva Purana then you should also know that we have lost A LOT of it from 100000 verses to 24000 verses. So who knows if some verse like that existed before. Anyways, if you DON'T BELIEVE then no prblm. I'm completely fine with that.Peace

Comment: BTW I want to ask something different from the topic which we discussed. The Mahabharata also has a incident involving the previous 7 births of Lord Brahma. Any comment on this? I just want your views like do you consider this as interpolation?

Comment: @LSSJ Broly After looking through some scriptures like the Srimad Bhagavatam, I have come to realize Brahma is a position. I could not remember what chapter or verse it was, but it said you are eligible for Brahma after 100 righteous rebirths, and if you exceed a lot more, you are eligible for the position of Shiva. I don't think it's an interpolation anymore, sorry.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for giving your views.

Comment: @Harihara I have a doubt. Where you read the incident about Lord Shiva saving Markandeyaji from Lord Yama which you told in the comment? Could you please let me know, I want that as a reference for some work.

Comment: @LSSJ Broly Now that I think about it, I've only seen paintings of this happening but when I searched, could not find any reference to Shiva saving Markandeya. The Shiva Purana's Uma Samhita in 3.5 states it very briefly that Shiva saved Markandeya in 1 sentence. Similarly, the Srimad Bhagvatam's 12th Skanda, 10.36 states that Shiva did save Markandeya and granted him longevity, but I could not find a detailed story like the ones I was told. Skanda Purana was the main one that narrated a long story about Markandeya's life.

Comment: Yes. We do not get that story in the puranas. I've heard many people say that it is only a folklore that originated from Tamil nadu. I thought that maybe I missed reading this somewhere and hence asked. If you get any references in future please provide it to me. Thanks.

Comment: according bannaje is 19th tretha yuga ramayana happened bakasura & mayaasura are there in ramayana also, infact mayasur is father in law of ravana, who helped pandava build indraprastha palace with all the latest technology, its isthe same mayasur, i too have confusion how come this asuras happened live yuga after yuga.. it also means in every dwapara krishna didnt born..